# Sublime Text 3: Stop opening a blank window every time after building with Latex

Tags: latex, sublimetext4

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Windows. After I update it to Build 4113, it starts opening a new window every time after I build pdf with Latex. I check the changelog, and find the following updates:

[image: updates].

I think this may be the problem. Then how to stop this?

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.